# Why is the logout action not accessible?

Tags: php, authentication, cakephp-2.0, logout

I want to let `Auth` give access to `login()`, `logout()` and `add()` action of my users controller, but it doesn't matter if I use `$this->Auth->allow('logout');` or not I get the message: `You are not authorized to access that location.` `login()` and `add()` work fine though.

This is my AppContoller.php:

```
class AppController extends Controller {

    public $components = array(

        'Auth' => array(
            'authenticate' => array(
                'Form' => array(
                    'userModel' => 'User',
                    'fields' => array(
                    'username' => 'email', 'password' => 'password')
                    )

            ), 

            'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'index'),
            'logoutRedirect' => array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display', 'landing')
        ), 'Session'
    );

    public function beforeFilter() {
        $this->Auth->allow('add', 'login');
    }

}
```

And this is the relevant part of my UsersController.php:

```
    public $helpers = array('Html', 'Form', 'Session');
    public $components = array('Session');


    public function beforeFilter() {

        parent::beforeFilter();
        $this->Auth->allow('logout');

    }
    public function logout() {
        $this->set('title_for_layout', 'Logout');
        $this->redirect($this->Auth->logout());
    }
```

Does anyone see the problem here? I appreciate your help.

Comment: On a quick glance I can see one minor problem, there's no point setting a title before a redirect, although it shouldn't be a factor in your problem.  The page you're redirecting to is Auth->allowed?

Comment: @Daniel, yes, as you can see in the beforeFilter function of UserController.php it is auth allowed.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the logoutRedirect action - /pages/display/landing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are accessing to logout action without problems but the logout redirection destroys your session and redirects you to a `page` view.

It seems you don't have access to the page without being logged. (you can try it accessing to the URL without being logged)

Add the `beforeFilter` function at your `PagesController`:

```
public function beforeFilter(){
    parent::beforeFilter();

    $this->Auth->allow();
}
```

PagesController comes by default with CakePHP 2.2, if you don't have it, just copy and paste any other controller and add this function deleting all the rest.

EDITED:
If the PagesController was already there, just add the beforeFilter function.

Comment: Oh great, the answer I was obviously leading to after making sure of the problem.  Thanks.

Comment: Could you please mark the answer as valid clicking on the ticket at the left of my answer?

Comment: Don't, at least until it's been edited - Steve's suggestion of removing the functions from PagesController is poor, it removes the display action that the questioner is obviously depending on using.

Comment: I was not talking about removing the display action or whatever inside the PagesController. I was talking about deleting the stuff in case he copies and paste another controller to create this one (because if i dont remember bad, it was not created by default in other CakePHP versions) (and sorry, I didn't read your comment on the question). Anyway, I would clarify it...

Comment: Most of the answer's fine, just this line "add this function deleting all the rest".  The problem is that dropping in PagesController in `/app/Controllers` will override the one Cake uses.  He'll therefore need a display() function in his PagesController as well.

Comment: @Daniel, Steve's answer was exactly the solution to my problem. I already knew about PagesController.php, so the explanation about that wasn't necessary, but thanks Steve.

Comment: @Loolooii I'm glad your problem has been solved.  The answer as it currently stands, however, wouldn't be of use to someone not familiar with PagesController.   In the hopes of informing a future user - as a good answer should - I move we edit the answer to reflect this, and delete the comments in the name of clarity.